# why do the legs rotate automatically during a walking animation?

Tags: animation, rigging

**When i put the legs forward, they rotate around their own axis at a certain distance. Does anyone know a solution to get a straight movement? Thank you[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUTVm.jpg)**

Comment: Maybe you need to change the IK's Pole Angle? If it doesn't fix your problem, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. Unfortunately, the change of the pole Angle had no positive impact... the file should be available now.

Comment: No it is not, you need to copy the address of this page, then paste it in blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com , agree to conditions, then copy the link it will give you and paste it here  ;)

Comment: It looks to me like the pole target bone isn't moving with the foot, causing the knee to pass in front of it and then flip around so that it still points at it. The usual solution to this is to parent the pole target bone to the foot bone.

Comment: It works! thank you for the good advice